# Upload without memory - stream file not possible with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Im trying to upload my large file (about 1 gb) with python-requests, but it doesnt stream - loads it to memory.

```
with open('file.rar','rb') as ff:
    upload = requests.post(host,files={"file": ff})
```

as documentation says, i tried:

```
with open('file.rar','rb') as ff:
    upload = requests.post(host,data=ff)
```

and its working, but i need to modify other POST fields. How to do this in python-requests?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for requests package at 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Which says in part the below, you need files= and a bit of python dict wrapper. Not sure if that is what you wanted.  But this pattern is allows you to modify the other fields by putting them in a dict passed to the data parameter as I see it.

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
   "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
,
 ...
```

}